# SpringBoot and setting system properties

Tags: spring-boot, oracle-coherence

I develop SpringBoot app that conntects to Oracle Coherence cluster. App, as coherence node need some JVM properties to connect to cluster. I wanted to set this properties (taken from properties file) in spring boot custom starter. I set system properties in `@Configuration` class and I can read those without problem but coherence doesn't see one property `tangosol.pof.enabled` and it fails. When I call `System.getProperty(..)` it is there but not working (property is not seen by coherence).

It works when I `@Autowire` configuration class in some other bean in my application or when I have this configuration class not in spring boot starter but in my application.

This is my code:

Configuration class in starter (it works)

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("coherence-app.properties")
public class EnvironmentConfig {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EnvironmentConfig.class);

    public EnvironmentConfig(Environment environment, ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        ConfigsHelper.TANGOSOL_COHERENCE_CONFIGS.stream()
                .forEach(prop -> props.setProperty(prop, environment.getProperty(prop)));

        if (!ConfigsHelper.setTangosolCoherenceProperties(props)){
            LOGGER.error("Can't set coherence props");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Then when I try to connect to cluster:

```
CacheFactory.ensureCluster();
```

I have error:

> 2017-08-09 13:17:56.049/7.494 Oracle Coherence GE 12.2.1.0.2 
>   (thread=Cluster, member=n/a): Failed to deserialize the config Message
>   received from member 1. This member is configured with the following
>   serializer: com.tangosol.io.DefaultSerializer
>   {loader=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2}, which may be
>   incompatible with the serializer configured by the sender.
>   java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type: 100   at
>   com.tangosol.util.ExternalizableHelper.readObjectInternal(ExternalizableHelper.java:2477)
>     at
>   com.tangosol.util.ExternalizableHelper.readObject(ExternalizableHelper.java:2464)
>     at
>   com.tangosol.io.DefaultSerializer.deserialize(DefaultSerializer.java:66)
>     at
>   com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.Service.readObject(Service.CDB:1)
>     at
>   com.tangosol.coherence.component.net.Message.readObject(Message.CDB:1)
>     at
>   com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.ClusterService$ServiceJoining.read(ClusterService.CDB:14)
>     at
>   com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.Grid.deserializeMessage(Grid.CDB:20)
>     at
>   com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.Grid.onNotify(Grid.CDB:21)
>     at
>   com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.ClusterService.onNotify(ClusterService.CDB:3)
>     at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.run(Daemon.CDB:45)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

It is connected with tangosol.pof.enabled=false property. 
Strange is that when I call

```
System.getProperty("tangosol.pof.enabled")
```

before ensureCluster it's true.

This code works properly when it's not in starter. Then configuration bean is initializing earlier and works.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: Not really clear what oracle-coherence is, but is whatever library the props are being used for expecting a `boolean`? From where do you call ensureCluster?

Comment: I tried to call ensureCluster from several places. Fo example from contexRefreshed event. Every time after setting system properties. Strange is that other props like tangosol.coherence.cacheconfig are set properly. Only that one is problematic.

Comment: Where do you actually use the properties though? Something like Client c = new Client(props)? Where does that stuff happen.

Comment: I dont use it in my code. Coherence libraries use it to configure node. It is used behind the scenes